# Issue in inserting values to table through jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I got this exception while using one of the answers from stackoverflow.

> You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause

This is my query and am using JSP to pass queries:

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO tablename(SL_No,candidate,phone,pan,mailid) 
                      VALUES(SELECT (MAX(SL_No)+1 newSL_No from tablename), ?, ?, ?, ? ))";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tablename(SL_No,candidate,phone,pan,mailid) 
select MAX(SL_No) + 1, ?, ?, ?, ?
from tablename
```

But actually it looks like you could just use the *auto-increment* of the SQL engine to do `MAX(SL_No) + 1`. If you change to column to that then your statement would be

```
INSERT INTO tablename(candidate,phone,pan,mailid) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: sorry that was an editing mistake..i will correct question

Comment: You cannot use `values` and  `select` together

Comment: No actually i want that column increment only when a condition is true that why am trying this

Comment: i used the mentioned code, now am getting:" Unknown column 'SL_No' in 'field list'"

Comment: sorry.... my bad.. i had missed a part of your above mentioned code now it works.thanks for helping :)